convert an object datatype to datetime
My date in my column looks like this:



Date




9999-12-31 00:00:00



I want to covert the  type of the column Date to datetime.
Because i have a time in the column with 00:00:00 i can't use the function to_datetime['Date']. If i use the to_datatime['date'] it will give me an error.
I know that you can add errors =coerce and then it will give NaT values back and is not what i want.
i wrote a small function below which keeps my original values. It's not converting to the type = datetime
adr_df['HIS_TS_END'] = adr_df['HIS_TS_END'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f') if type(x)==str else pd.NaT)
print(type(adr_df.iloc[0][1]))

What do i need to add so my datatype will be datetime?

Sorry, what's the question? I'm not really following what you wrote. For tips, see [ask]. You can [edit] to clarify.

If it helps, check out How to make good reproducible pandas examples

I try to clear my quetions, do you understand now what im trying to ask

OK, I get what you're asking now, but I don't think you understand the problem. Did you read the error? OverflowError: value too large ... OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 9999-12-31 00:00:00. Have you read the documentation? Timestamp limitations: "For nanosecond resolution, the time span that can be represented using a 64-bit integer is limited to approximately 584 years ... When choosing second-resolution, the available range grows to +/- 2.9e11 years."

To be clear, the error has nothing to do with the time being midnight, it's because the year 9999 is out of range.

ah oke, but how can i handle this problem

Oh, I just noticed you have some major typos: to_datetime['Date'] and to_datatime['date'] should be pd.to_datetime(df['Date']), assuming your dataframe is called df. Otherwise you'd get different errors than the ones I mentioned.

My data frame is called adr_df  im still getting this erorr

Did you read the docs I linked?

yes i have like you said the range is to big. But it don't get how to handle it

In what way? Please, be more detailed.

So what i understand is if you have a bigger timestamp then i follow this : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-oob is that the righ way by using the Peroindex

That's one option, but I'm not sure a PeriodIndex would work here. Another is to use second-resolution, like it says. There's a question about that since the interface doesn't really exist yet: How do I parse a list of datetimes with a 's' resolution in pandas 2?

Yes did worked thank you, maby you can add it in the answer then i can mark this as correct .Thank you very much

Welcome :) I'm not sure what an answer would look though. This question might be effectively a duplicate of the other question I linked.

If you work in the valid range it works:
import pandas as pd
import datetime

date =["2024-12-31 01:01:01"]
df = pd.DataFrame(date, columns=['date'])

df = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print(df.dtype)

If you need a greater range you can find a solution here

if you want to convert your column to datetime:
adr_df['HIS_TS_END'] = pd.to_datetime(adr_df['HIS_TS_END'])



This raises an error for that input: OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 9999-12-31 00:00:00
